# I am having issues while deploying react and node application on unix standalone server

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have developed my application on a windows machine and have to deploy this on a standalone UNIX server and while running commands like: `npm start`, it says that package is not available but I checked and everything is available in the project's npm modules.

Do I need to use docker or how can I achieve that without any container such as `docker` or `kubernete`.

Can I try cloning my repo in some other Linux machine and npm install and then use the same folder to deploy on UNIX CentOS running on the server?

Comment: There is sometimes useful information in the log files when environments don't match. You might have a some relevant log files in `/var/log`. Do you have shell access to the server? If so, do `ls /var/log` and look for a `nodejs` directory.

Comment: Also, give us a bit more detail on what precise error you're getting. That'll help us debug the problem!

Comment: Yes, i checked logfile. It says that concurrently module is not found but i checked and it is in the npm folder. I think it is happening becuase binaries are getting generated as .cmd and which is not getting recognised in unix.

Comment: Have you installed `concurrently` globally on your Linux machine? Check out [the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently#install) on how to do that.

Comment: Yes, i cross checked. it is available.